# using tinymce wih django admin panel

Tags: django, tinymce

I am trying to integrate tinymce with django using [these steps](http://django-tinymce.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release-1.5/docs/.build/html/usage.html#the-htmlfield-model-field-type), however I can't. All I see in my admin panel is a simple TextField.

It seems there is something wrong with my settings.py file because in the code of the admin page I get this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.__admin_media_prefix__ = "/static/admin/";</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/admin/jsi18n/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/core.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/jquery.init.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/actions.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
```

Shouldn't tiny_mce.js source file exist in static/admin directory? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: that seems exactly right actually

Comment: maybe [this](http://vimeo.com/12903891) will help coz it helped me :)

Answer (score 1):

First - look at this code throught Firebug (or something else, as you wish), maybe .js code doesn't linked with that page, then you will see 404 page there. Also, if everything correct you must check javascript errors, maybe there some dependencies fails.

And I'm sure, that you connect all needed code inn your .py files.